# Is there any difference between the expression "be on for something" and "be up for something"?

Tags: difference, phrases

Is there any difference between the expression *be on for something* and *be up for something*? For example:

> Hey, are you still **on for** lunch?
>
> Hey, are you still **up for** lunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtle but definite difference. To be "on for" something means to be scheduled for that thing. To be "up for" something means to be willing to undertake that thing, or interested in doign so, possibly eager to do it.

So: "Are you on for lunch?" means are you scheduled to have lunch, possibly in a particular place or with a particular group, depending on context. It suggests a previous arrangement that is beign confirmed.

In contrast: "Are you up for lunch?" Means "are you willing to have lunch" probably implying "with me" or "with the group just mentioned", depending on context again.

However, in casual speech "on for" might be used to mean "willing to schedule for".

"Are you still on for X" more definitely indicates a prior arrangement that is now being conformed, or else canceled. "Are you still up for X" also strongly implies a prior arrangement, or at least a prior discussion of X, but the listener's continued interest in X is being questioned.

Both of these are rather informal in tone, particularly "up for" in my experience.